# XSLT-based replacements on different nesting levels

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is the XML document with the key elements `sr` and `ds` on different nesting levels:

```
<doc>
  <p>
    <sr>some text 1</sr>
    <ds>some text 2</ds>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>
      <sr>some text 3</sr>
      <ds>some text 4</ds>
    </span>
    <span>
      <sr><b>some</b> text 5</sr>
      <ds>some text <sup>6</sup></ds>
    </span>
  </p>
  <td colspan="2">
    <sr><b>some</b> text 7</sr>
    <ds>some text <b>8</b></ds>
  </td>
</doc>
```

The task is to output it as HTML as is, but in case `<sr>` and `<ds>` elements are encountered, perform some modifications on parent element whatever it will be:

1. put the contents of `sr` into `title` attribute of parent element removing all the nested tags; only plain text should remain
2. put the contents of `ds` element as is to the body of parent element, with all the nested tags

For example, the above document should look like:

```
<body>
  <p title="some text 1">some text 2</p>
  <p>
    <span title="some text 3">some text 4</span>
    <span title="some text 5">some text <sup>6</sup></span>
  </p>
  <td colspan="2" title="some text 7">some text <b>8</b></td>
</body>
```

Is this possible  with XSLT?

Currently I know only how to handle XML elements on a fixed nesting level like `<xsl:for-each select="/level1/level2">` or how to select elements on various levels but select only them, while my task is to output the rest as is.

Could you give a clue?

Sometimes I think it would be simpler to read the document entirely into a string and do a series of plain string replaces without XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sr">
    <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ds">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note this assumes that `sr` will always precede `ds` or any other sibling element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that **works regardless of the order of the `sr` and `ds` elements**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::ds )]|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[sr and ds]" priority="8">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:value-of select="sr"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/*" priority="9">
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="sr" priority="10"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this variation of the provided XML document** (note the arbitrary order of `sr` and `ds`):

```
<doc>
  <p>
    <ds>some text 2</ds>
    <sr>some text 1</sr>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>
      <sr>some text 3</sr>
      <ds>some text 4</ds>
    </span>
    <span>
      <sr><b>some</b> text 5</sr>
      <ds>some text <sup>6</sup></ds>
    </span>
  </p>
  <td colspan="2">
    <ds>some text <b>8</b></ds>
    <sr><b>some</b> text 7</sr>
  </td>
</doc>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<body>
   <p title="some text 1">some text 2</p>
   <p>
      <span title="some text 3">some text 4</span>
      <span title="some text 5">some text <sup>6</sup>
      </span>
   </p>
   <td colspan="2" title="some text 7">some text <b>8</b>
   </td>
</body>
```